# Prove that there are no positive integers $n>1$ and $k>1$ such that $n!=k^k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that there are no positive integers $n>1$ and $k>1$ such that $n!=k^k$.

Can anybody help me?

if $n=k$ then $n!\neq k^k$,

if $n<k$, then $n!\neq k^k$,

if $n\geqslant2k$, then $n!\neq k^k$,

if $k<n<2k$ i don't know what to do. Maybe it is wrong way.

Comment: Do you know Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: This question can be improved if you tell us where got this problem from (e.g. homework) and giving us a sense of what your background is (e.g. are you taking a course in number theory or proof writing?). As it is, the question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: Given the prime factors of $k$, what are the prime factors of $k^k$? What about he prime factors of $n!$?

Comment: if $k=n$ then $n!$ not equals $k^k$, if k>n, then $n!$ not equals $k^k$, but if $k<n<2k$ i dont know what to do. May be it is wrong way.

Comment: @RuslanLotakov That method might work... the way I think you should do it is first trying to see when $n!$ divides $k^k$, and then prove if $n!$ divides $k^k$, they cannot be equal.

Comment: its intuitive a bit because you can only have so many prime factors in k^k

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $n!=k^k$ with $n>1$.
Let $p$ be a prime $\le n$. Then $p\mid n!$ implies $p\mid k^k$, hence $p\mid k$.
So let $p_1=2,p_2=3,\ldots, p_r$ be all the primes $\le n$.
Then from the above, we have $p_1p_2\cdots p_r\mid k$ and in particular $k\ge p_1p_2\cdots p_r$.
From Euklid's proof of the infinitude of primes, we remember that there exists a prime $q\le p_1p_2\cdots p_r+1$ that differs from all $p_i$. Thus in our situation we conclude $n<q$ and in particular $n\le p_1p_2\cdots p_r\le k$.
But then $k^k\ge n^n>n!$, contradiction.